# golangci-lint проверяет то что мне не нужно (goland)

Tags: golang, linter

ОС: windows
IDE: goland 2020.1

Хочу в goland добавить golangci-lint (в VSC вообще проблем не было), в настройках file watchers
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не работает.

Плагин go linter стоит, только не понятно как сделать что бы он работал, т.е. не не проверяет линтеры от golangci-lint.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IDE выдает такие ошибки ошибки, только не понятно что за конфиг, я же его руками не настраиваю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А самое странное, это то, что если выполнить `golangci-lint run .` в терминале (в каталоге с проектом)
golangci-lint проверяет какие-то системные пакеты а не мой проект, вот пример вывода лога
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

содержимое `.golangci.yml`

```yml
run:
  tests: true
  skip-dirs:
    - bin

output:
  format: colored-line-number
  print-issued-lines: true
  print-linter-name: true

linters:
  enable-all: true
  disable:
    - gochecknoglobals
    - errcheck
    - gosimple
    - lll
```

Comment: вам нужно в корень проекта положить `.golangci.yml`  [подробнее тут](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/#config-file)

Comment: я про это забыл упомянуть, но он там есть (добавил в вопрос)

Comment: я попробовал у себя воспроизвести. к сожалению, не получается.  настройки как в первых двух картинках, а на третей конфиги берутся из файла.

Comment: возможно, вам стоит обновить плагин. в последней выложенной версии плагина go linter значится изменение "fix: correctly support .golangci.yaml config" https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12496-go-linter/versions/stable/97016